# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1}$ using Fourier series.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ s.t. $f(x)=e^{-x}$ on $[0,L)$ and s.t. $f(x+L)=f(x)$.

1) Find Fourier coefficient.

2) Deduce $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1}$.

For 1), I found $$c_n=\frac{1}{L+2i\pi n}\left(e^{-(L+2i\pi n)x}-1\right),$$

but how can I deduce 2) ? The thing I know it's that $$f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}c_ke^{\frac{2i\pi nx}{L}}$$
on $[0,L)$, but even, I can't conclude.

Comment: Use Parseval's theorem.

Comment: Your expression for $c_n = \frac{1}{L} \int_0^L f(x) e^{-2i \pi n x/L}dx$ is wrong (it should depend only on $n$). Then look at $|c_n|^2$

Comment: @user1952009: Don't we have $$c_n=\frac{1}{L}\int_0^L e^{-x}e^{-\frac{2i\pi nx}{L}}\mathrm d x=\frac{1}{L}\int_0^L e^{-(1+\frac{2i\pi n}{L})x}\mathrm d x=-\frac{1}{L+2i\pi n}\left[e^{-(1+\frac{2i\pi n}{L})x}\right]_0^L$$
$$=\frac{1}{L+2i\pi n}\left(e^{-(L+2i\pi n)x}-1\right).$$

Comment: When substituting values for $x$, the dependence on $x$ goes away.. Basically just get rid of $x$ in that last expression.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I don't understand. What's wrong in my calculation ?

Comment: Nothing. The last expression just cannot depend on $x$. You plugged in values for $x$ so.. it's gone. That's how definite integrals work.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: hahaha, I see now :-) Thank you

Comment: Note that you may need to pick a certain value of $L$..